# Find most expensive queries with Entity Framework / SQL server WITHOUT view server state permissions

Tags: sql, entity-framework

Usually when I finish a project, I like to run queries in SQL to see if any of my queries from the code are more expensive than they should be (basically, I want to make sure I didn't forget to put an index somewhere).  However, my company / the DBAs will not grant me permission to VIEW SERVER STATE, so I can't run the query I need to.

I am using Code-First EF, and am curious if there is any way to add some kind of "tracking" within Entity Framework to see what queries I might be able to optimize / apply indexing to a table somewhere.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you use SSMS to run your queries?  Maybe do you think you could persuade your DBAs to gather some SQL Profiler results for you?

Comment: Well..  this is resolved, but not.  Still curious about my original question, but I have a workaround.  I have VIEW DATABASE STATE permission, but the server this database is on doesn't have Query Store enabled.  We are moving the database tonight to a server that does have it enabled, which will solve my problem.

Comment: Ever looked at Glimpse?